# stuck on css parse error

Tags: css

I keep getting a parse error from the W3C css validation, but can not figure out what is wrong with my code. I have CSS label 3 selected when validating.

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .center {
        margin: auto 0;
        width: 80%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the error, please.

Comment: Your code passes this W3C validation service: https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator

Comment: There are no errors. CSSLint doesn't pick any up.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I was using http://www.css-validator.org/ for validation so this may have been the issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) you have to declare mediatype. An standard format is:

```
@media not|only mediatype and (media feature) {
    CSS-Code;
}
```

And your example may look like:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .center {
        margin: auto 0;
        width: 80%;
    }
}
```

Follow the above link for more information.